# Viable Late Game Alternative Barbarian Builds?

Tags: diablo-iii, diablo-iii-barbarian

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Building Barbarian in Inferno](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/69523/building-barbarian-in-inferno)

Someone recently asked about a barbarian build on inferno. The answer given was very detailed and overall pretty solid advice.

I'm curious if there are any Barbarians who are using a different build in inferno than the one stated here: https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/69553/10991.

To summarize the build is :

- Frenzy w/ Triumph
- Revenge w/ Provocation
- Leap w/ Iron Impact
- Ignore Pain w/ Ignorance is Bliss
- Wraith of the Beserker w/ Insanity
- War Cry w/ Impurity

Are there any builds out that take a different approach to inferno barbarian ? Or is this  the end-all build for Barbarians ?

I ask because the devs really emphasized how they wanted people to use different builds, but it's hard to see how someone could survive without frenzy and revenge.

Comment: If you want users to provide additional answers you should put a [bounty on the other question](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/privileges/set-bounties), you shouldn't ask another question.

Comment: Are you saying this is a possible duplicate of the question i linked to ?

Comment: What would adding a bounty to the other question do ? The question already has an answer with 28 upvotes, why would I give up rep to see an answer that is already available ?

Comment: Yes, this is a duplicate of the question  you linked to, because all you're asking for is additional answers to the other question. The purpose of the bounty is to attract new answers, not to reward the ones already there.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/3595/discussion-between-robotsushi-and-wipqozn)

Comment: @Robotsushi As the guy who wrote that answer, I can say with certainly that it's not the only workable build option. I've read about some others on the forums, but didn't add them to my answer because I haven't tried them yet. I'd love to see some other people post answers to that question of what works for them.