# How should I build a barbarian as I progress through Inferno?

Tags: diablo-iii, diablo-iii-barbarian

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Building Barbarian in Inferno](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/69523/building-barbarian-in-inferno)

I have read [this very popular barbarian building guide](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/69523/building-barbarian-in-inferno), but I didn't feel it answered this question: What should Barbarians look at changing or building in gear or stats when progressing through Inferno from Act 2 to Act 4?

Should there be a change in skills and passives?

Should there be even more resist, armour, then str/vit?

Or, should focus be on Crit % / Damage with the 1.03 3 minute enrage timer?

Comment: Hi, Leiko, welcome to Arqade!  Unfortunately, I'm going to vote to close your question as a duplicate of the one you linked; the question should apply to all of Inferno.  If it does not answer your question, we can request an update to the answers to take that into account.

Comment: @Leiko in what way doesn't the question you've linked answer your question? Please bare in mind that due to the many different ways you can configure your character in Diablo 3, the answer to the question you're asking regarding specific spec changes for different acts is very much down to your playstyle. The information provided in [Sterno's answer](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/69553/27134) is very comprehensive but is still heavily influenced by your own personal playstyle.

Comment: @Leiki I've added a post in the other thread about what gear to look for, hopefully that'll answer your question.