# How does armor stack with physical resistance?

Tags: diablo-iii

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do armor, resistances and missile/melee damage reduction interact?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/67319/how-do-armor-resistances-and-missile-melee-damage-reduction-interact)

Say I have 40% damage reduction from armor, and 15% from physical resistance.  How is my overall damage reduction calculated? (for physical sources)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To put it in a nutshell: if diablo hits you for 100 damage and you have 15% physical resistance he will hit you for 85 damage minus the 40% from armor, so minus 34. You'll get hit for 51 damage.

The same calculations apply to melee and range only that it's less of the overall monsters where you'll get the reduction. So you should prefer physical resistance over just melee or just range reduction unless it's significantly larger.

Also you should prefer melee over range reduction because the meelee's hit harder in general but i guess it's depending on your class a bit. A demonhunter might stack range reduction because of kiting ability while a barbarian should pretty much only get melee damage reduction or physical resistance.

Comment: Hmm, it's pretty easy to get to 50%+ reduction for both physical resistance & armor, which would result in you taking 0 damage according to that.  Are you sure about this approach?  (seems like a tremendous oversight on Blizz's part, if so)

Comment: The reduction from armor will only be on the 50% so you will not get a 100% damage reduction unless you get 100% from armor alone.

Comment: Sorry, a bit confused; you're saying it's multiplicative?  Also, wow, it turned out that I gave some bad example values too.  100 - 40 - 25 == 45, as well as 100 * .75 * .6 == 45.

Comment: Yeah it has to be. If it wasn't you could actually become invulnerable.

Comment: @Melini Damage reduction from armor is calculated `Armor / (Armor+(50*mLvl))` so because the calculation divides total armor by a larger number, you'll never get 100% damage reduction from armor alone.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation... that's what I was trying to say but math has never been my strong point >.<