# Should I build a resist set of gear?

Tags: diablo-iii

I'm working my way though Nightmare and I'm starting to get lots of drops with +resists.  Should I be saving some of these that kind-of fit with my class for later on?  Just save a particular resist set (e.g. Fire)?

Are there any encounters in Hell or up where you require a resist stat?

Comment: Just reached NM, and I have a sub-question for those replying: should I save +fire resist for molten fire chains elites?

Answer (score 6):

Since Armor protects against all types of damage, it is unlikely that resist gear that you find in Nightmare is going to be better than equipment you find later on with significantly higher armor.  So I don't think it makes sense to try to hold on to resist gear over a levelling up period.  You should only grab a bunch if you need it short term, or once you've gotten high enough level that armor values won't be increasing significantly anymore.

Comment: I agree... I made the mistake of starting to invest in +30-ish resist gear on my Barbarian while running Hell, only to find out that really for Inferno, I'd want pieces with +50 or more. No sense grabbing Nightmare gear for later... you'll want better by the time you need it.

Comment: Armor reduces magic damage?

Comment: @NickT Armor reduces **all** damage. See [this SE question](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/67319/how-do-armor-resistances-and-missile-melee-damage-reduction-interact) and also [this Blizzard forum post](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/forum/topic/5149150485). Short versions if you want to find an equilibrium between resistance and armor.