# What rule system does Diablo III use?

Tags: diablo-iii

I am really interested in the actual calculations behind damage, how stats increase, avoidance calculations (e.g., miss chance, dodge, etc.), and so on.

How are these calculated? Is Diablo based on a role-playing system (such as GURP) whose calculations are publicly available?

Comment: Diablo doesn't use AD&D or GURPS. There are a lot of questions on the topic here, search for 'damage reduction', 'dodge' etc.

Comment: @Alok The most comprehensive answer I could find is this one: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/67319/how-do-armor-resistances-and-missile-melee-damage-reduction-interact/68192#68192 (Sternos answer) however I was wondering if there is some sort of standard system/grand overview

Comment: Hi Zainodis welcome to Gaming.SE! bwarner answered the "Is Diablo based on a role-playing system?" question, but in terms of a grand overview, Stack Exchange works a bit differently from other game sites and [doesn't generally do strategy guides like that](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/a/3722/3389). Instead, we focus on specific questions: you'll find a number of questions about specific stats here like the one you found about resistances and damage reduction.

Comment: @MarkTrapp Thanks for the hint :) acutally I am a developer coming from Stackoverflow, so I am sorry, I wasn't fully aware of how you handle things here. On an additional note: It's not so much for playing the game, as it is for understanding the system behind it for a custom implementation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no comprehensive list of rules yet, but the fine folks at [MMO Mechanics](http://mmo-mechanics.com/swtor/forums/Thread-Diablo-3-formula-list) have spaded a list of formulas to start off.

### Player Life

**Life when player level < 35** = 36 + 4 × Level + 10 × Vitality

**Life when player level ≥ 35** = (level - 25) × Vitality

### Damage

**Damage on Character Sheet** = (1 + passive skill boosts)*(Weapon DPS + ((minimum damage bonus + maximum damage bonus)/2)*Attack Speed)*(Weapon Damage Multipliers)*(Attack Speed / Weapon Speed)*(1 + ( crit% * crit damage %))*( 1 + (main stat / 100))

**Spell Damage Modifier** = (1 + passive skill boosts)(Weapon Damage + (minimum damage bonus + maximum damage bonus) / 2)(1 + (main stat / 100))

### Defense

**Total damage reduction** = 1 - ((1 - DR from Armor) × (1 - DR from Resistance) × (1 - other DR))

**Physical damage reduction** = Armor / (50 × Monster Level + Armor)

**Elemental damage reduction** = Resistance / (5 × Monster Level + Resistance)

### Offense

**APS** (attacks per second) = base weapon APS × (1 + dual wield bonus + other attack speed bonuses)

### Experience

```
Monster level compared to character level      XP gain
3 levels higher and above                      125%
2 levels higher                                    120%
1 level higher                                     115%
Same level monster                             100%
1 level lower                                       90%
2 levels lower                                      80%
3 levels lower                                      70%
4 levels lower                                      60%
5 levels lower                                      45%
6 levels lower                                      30% (no +XP/kill from gear)
7 levels lower                                      15% (no +XP/kill from gear)
8 levels lower                                       5% (no +XP/kill from gear)
9 levels lower                                       1% (no +XP/kill from gear)
```

### Group Mechanics

Normal

```
# Players   HP%    Damage %
1           100%    100%
2           175%    100%
3           250%    100%
4           325%    100%
```

Nightmare

```
# Players   HP%    Damage %
1           100%    100%
2           185%    100%
3           270%    100%
4           355%    100%
```

Hell

```
# Players   HP%    Damage %
1           100%    100%
2           195%    100%
3           290%    100%
4           385%    100%
```

Inferno

```
# Players   HP%    Damage %
1           100%    100%
2           210%    100%
3           320%    100%
4           430%    100%
```

Answer (score 3):

Diablo 3 is not based on a pen-and-paper role playing system.  All of the systems were designed specifically for Diablo 3.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, and I guess Diablo III's system is not publicly available?

Comment: Nope, the only information that is known about it is what Blizzard has disclosed or what people have figured out through experimentation.

Comment: Thank you, I guess then I'll have to try to gather those information based on what you said.

Comment: @Zainodis You'd probably be interested in this: http://mmo-mechanics.com/swtor/forums/Thread-Diablo-3-formula-list

Comment: Interestingly, Diablo 2 was roughly based on D&D concepts such as THAC0, but these have been scrapped in Diablo 3.

Comment: @Resorath Interesting, I didn't know that, as I only played Diablo II way back, when I was a kid and then I didn't know about the mechanics of a Game at all :)

Comment: @Mr.November Thanks a LOT for that reference! Actually if you would like to post it, wrapped in an answer, I'd make it the correct answer, as it was a lot more helpful, than the current answer.

Comment: @Zainodis Done!